# Install Package in Jupyter Notebook, Anaconda

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, rstudio

I'm running R language with Jupyter Notebook using Anaconda via Environments - not R Studio.

I'm trying to install R packages but it gives me the following errors:

`install.packages('agricolae', repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")`

`also installing the dependencies ‘units’, ‘sf’, ‘spdep’`

`Warning message in install.packages("agricolae", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/"):
“installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("agricolae", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/"):
“installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("agricolae", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/"):
“installation of package ‘spdep’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("agricolae", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/"):
“installation of package ‘agricolae’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done`

Then I try to load the library

`library("agricolae")`

Error in library("agricolae"): there is no package called ‘agricolae’
Traceback:

1. library("agricolae")

If I open with R Studio, I can make it work.

Does anybody know how to solve the issue on Jupyter Notebook?, I'm using macOs sierra 10.12.6.

Thank you very much

Comment: It worked fine in my case. I guess you are installing the package not into conda environment, but in your regular location for R packages. Check `.libPaths()` both from within RStudio and the Jupyter Notebook. Are they different? In your Notebook it should look like ".... anaconda3/envs/Anaconda-R/Lib/R/library' or similar

Comment: If you know in which directory you must/want to install the Package, you can either use install.packages("agricolae", lib="PathToDirectory) o you can permanently add this directory via .libPaths

Comment: Same problem here, although I'm trying to install the "sf" package. Like you it cannot install the 'units' dependency. Anaconda, jupyter, R 3.6. Works fine in plain R , Rstudio etc. Paths are fine.